# How can we differentiate between images having same histogram?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I calculated the histogram of a sequence of images using OpenCV, but at some point even if the image is having different look their histograms are same as a result of which the entropy and histogram difference is also coming out to be same.

How can one differentiate between those kind of images here?

Please help!

Comment: The obvious answer is that you shouldn't compare the images through the histograms then. That is a known issue when relying solely on the histograms. There are many other ways to compare images, and if you include some sample images that you are trying to compare, more relevant suggestions/answers are likely to appear.

Comment: how bout just comparing the images?

Comment: A histogram typically looks at an image as it it were black and white. You might try histograms of the individual channels, so that you get a red histogram, green histogram and blue histogram and compare.

Another technique would be to subtract one image from the other, then do a histogram of the resulting image. This histogram would measure the difference of the images.

Comment: @FredF that doesn't make sense at all. Are you saying that given any image, a histogram will typically show two bins only ? One for black, and other for white ? That would only be true for binary images. Then following you suggest using RGB histograms, but what if the input image is a grayscale one ? This makes no difference. Now, after you subtract an image from another to perform further analysis, you lose the good thing that a histogram provides: it is a short (and trivial) signature of the image that doesn't depend on any other image.

Comment: When he said black and white i think he meant gray scale. Which is 255 shades of gray, not just black and white.

Answer (score 0):

If the input image is grayscale, then there is only 1 channel, most images these days are color. If the file is grayscale, then there is only 1 channel.

Here is something easy to try. For grayscale, you could average every row of pixels to get a single grayscale value, then produce a histogram of the row averages, while at the same time make an average of every column value and make a histogram of that.

Over simplyfying the results. If you have 3 files,

one which has the left half black and the right half white.

one which has the top black and the bottom white

one which has a checkerboard of black and white squares.

A standard histogram would show 50% of the pixels black and 50% of them white.

A horizontal histogram would show the left/right and the checkerboard as having all 50% gray while the top/bot would have 50% black & 50% white

A vertical histogram would show the top/bot and the checkerboard having all 50% gray, while the left/right would show a 50%black and 50% white.

So while all 3 files would have the same base histogram, they would be unique by the horizontal histograms.

The horizontal histograms are low resolution, since they are averages, so you'd still want the full historgram for primary identification.

Of course you can also come up with other averages besides horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Averaging rows will just cause even more "histogram conflicts", i.e., different images with same histograms.

Comment: Not when the 3 histograms are used together. The standard histogram would still be the primary source of uniqueness. Only when multiple images have the first level of histogram similar would the secondary ones be used for differentiation. It would be like the first histogram is a name, like "John Smith" and the secondary histograms are height and weight. So with multiple John Smiths, one of the John smith is 5'10" and 180 pounds, while a second John Smith is 6'1" and 380 pounds.

Comment: One standard procedure in computer vision is to use histogram pyramids to preserve some spatial information that otherwise gets lost. [Here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/caltech/phog.html) is an example where they use gradients instead of gray values. But he idea should still apply.